# PC only has an Ethernet port. Can I use a RJ11 to RJ45 joiner adapter and dial out?

Tags: modem

I obtained a PC from a  sale. It is a Dell  Dimension 4500S PC with a internal modem, but at the back of the computer, there’s only a ethernet port and no (RJ11) phone jack port.

I have dial-up internet service, can i use a RJ11 (phone line) to RJ45 (Ethernet) joiner adapter and hook it up to my PC, and dial out to the Internet?

Comment: If it's an ethernet port, why do you think there is an internal modem?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the ethernet port to connect to your dial-up service.  The machine may have an internal modem on the mother board, but if there is no RJ11 present, then the required adapter cable is not provided.

However, for $4 shipped, you can get a PCI based modem from EBAY that will go into that machine.  Try searching for 'Dell 4500 56K PCI FAX/MODEM'